# Show cursor in command-line mode

Tags: vim, command-line

When I type `:` in normal mode cursor becomes invisible and when I do mapping which contains function calling, cursor starts blink. It is possible to always show cursor, even in command-line mode? Or can I call function in normal mode without typing `:`?

Comment: By cursor I mean the cursor over the buffer text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one cursor because in the terminal, the cursor is a terminal feature, and there is only one such per terminal.

I guess the reason for asking is that you need a visual indication of the current cursor position while composing a command-line call.

There are several possibilities to achieve this:

#### permanent cursor position highlighting

```
autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter * match Cursor /\%#./
```

This defines a window-local `:match` of the current position, via the special `\%#` regular expression atom.

This will apply to all windows. Ensure that the `Cursor` highlight group actually is discernible; not all colorschemes have this.

#### cmdline-only highlighting

Alternatively, you could enable on entering command-line mode only:

```
function! HighlightCursor( isOn, key )
    if a:isOn
        match Cursor /\%#./
        redraw
    else
        match
    endif
    return a:key
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> : HighlightCursor(1, ':')
cnoremap <expr> <CR> HighlightCursor(0, "\<lt>CR>")
```

#### crosshair lines

```
:set cursorline cursorcolumn
```

The intersection of current line and current column is the cursor position.